# CodeSite alternative for 64-bit C# development

Tags: c#, visual-studio, 64-bit, codesite

I have used [Raize CodeSite](http://www.raize.com/DevTools/CodeSite/Default.asp) for years - first in Delphi and now in Visual Studio. I recently upgraded my development machine to a 64-bit OS. I was pleasantly surprised that everything just came up and worked - until I tried to use CodeSite in a C# app that targets 'Any CPU'. Turns out there is a known issue with 64-bit apps.

As much as I love CodeSite, I need to move on, but I have really grown dependent on this type of tool.

Can anyone suggest an alternative to CodeSite?

--Bruce

Comment: Very interesting question - for my .NET development, I had to resort back down the basic debug string outputs (using the System.Diagnostics facilities) - a big step back from CodeSite :-( Wonder if they're something out there that works for 64-bit .NET stuff, too!

Answer (score 2):

Some things you might want to consider for gaining insight into your executing code include:

[Profile Sharp](http://www.softprodigy.net/products) (Open Source)
[dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) (Commercial)
[http://www.eqatec.com/tools/profiler](http://EQATEC) (Free)